# Getting Google Chrome out of memory issue due to multiple dropdown list gets populated dynamically in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, browser, tags, struts-1

Getting Google Chrome out of memory issue due to multiple dropdown list gets populated dynamically in JSP page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<nested:iterate property="studentList">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <nested:select property="name">
        <html:options collection="college" property="test1" />
      </nested:select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</nested:iterate>
```

Comment: Snippet can't run due out of language error.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided. JSP is rendered on the server side; only the rendered HTML could cause a Chrome issue (unlikely, but possible) or, if it's being populated "dynamically", like via JS, then *that* is the cause of the problem, and we can't see it.